# Python Print Output Executing Out of Order

Tags: python

with respect to my code below (Python language), why does the following print statement (in the get_a_maximal_subset function)

```
    file = open("_probe","a")
    file.write("\n new_ref_array: \n")
    file.write(str(new_ref_array))
    file.close
```

get printed to the file before the (in the reference code below)

```
                        file = open("_probe","a")
                        file.write("\n local_array \n")
                        file.write(str(local_array))
                        file.close
```

I get the following output in the _probe file:

test point 2

test point 3

test point 3-b

test point 3-c

new_ref_array:

[10, 1]

new_ref_array:

[10, 1]

local_array

[10, 1]

test point 4

ISSUE: it seems that the "local array" should be printed BEFORE instead of after the "new_ref_array" lines, since the "new_ref_array" lines are from the get_a_maximal_array function and the code order is:

```
                        local_array = list(array[i:])
                        file = open("_probe","a")
                        file.write("\n local_array \n")
                        file.write(str(local_array))
                        file.close
                        i = i + 1
                        subset_candidate = get_a_maximal_subset(local_array, max, prefix)
```

====================MY CODE BELOW===========================================

```
                while (determination_process == True):
                    file = open("_probe","a")
                    file.write("\n test point 2 \n")
                    file.close
                    i = 0
                    for x in array:
                        file = open("_probe","a")
                        file.write("\n test point 3 \n")
                        file.close
                        prefix = []
                        local_process_ref = [max+1]
                        if (determination_process != True):
                            break
                        if (x not in global_process_ref):
                            file = open("_probe","a")
                            file.write("\n test point 3-b \n")
                            file.close
                            global_process_ref.append(x)
                            file = open("_probe","a")
                            file.write("\n test point 3-c \n")
                            file.close
                        local_array = list(array[i:])
                        file = open("_probe","a")
                        file.write("\n local_array \n")
                        file.write(str(local_array))
                        file.close
                        i = i + 1
                        subset_candidate = get_a_maximal_subset(local_array, max, prefix)
                        file = open("_probe","a")
                        file.write("\n test point 4 \n")
                        file.close
```

Comment: I don't see any `print` statements anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not closing the file when you do this:

```
file.close
```

You're just referencing the close method as a value. What you wanted was to *call* the close method:

```
file.close()
```

Eventually, the file gets garbage-collected, at which point all of its buffered data gets flushed. But meanwhile, you've opened the same file elsewhere and appended new data to it.

On many platforms, your left-over buffers would end up overwriting the later-appended data, instead of getting added after them, making this even harder to debug. You got lucky here. :)

---

If you ran this code through a linter, it would have warned you. With [`pylint`](http://www.pylint.org), I get "W0104: Statement seems to have no effect". However, note that it can't possibly catch all such errors. For example:

```
import random
r = random.random
```

Here, you're setting `r` to the `random` function, instead of to a random number from 0 to 1 as you probably wanted.

By `pylint` can't know that; the statement has an effect, and it could easily be a useful effect you *could* have wanted. In fact, I found two examples of exactly this statement grepping source (paraphrasing a bit):

```
def build_list(n):
    r=random.random # only do the global lookup once instead of n times
    return [r() for _ in range(1000000)]
```

… or for flexibility (although this is not a very good example):

```
def build_list(n, r=None):
    if r is None:
        if have_urandom:
            r = lambda: urandom.read(1)
        except IOError:
            r = random.random
    return [r() for _ in range(1000000)]
```

Comment: Seems like an easy mistake to make. Is there a good way to catch it? Lint or something?

Comment: @cbednarski: Yes, almost any linter will warn you about this. For example, with `pylint`, you'll get "W0104: Statement seems to have no effect".

Comment: @cbednarski: However, note that there are similar cases where a linter can't guess what you mean. For example, if you'd meant to call a function that returns something useful, and left off the parentheses—e.g., `value = random.random`—that's perfectly useful code; it's just setting `value` to a function instead of a random number.

Comment: @abarnert: THAT WAS THE ANSWER - MILLION THANKS!!